# In CSS, If the default behavior of position: absolute is display:block then why is my output showing otherwise[display:inline-block]

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```
div
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.first-container
{
  background-color: #9AD0EC;
}

.second-container
{
  background-color: red;
  left: 200px;
}

.third-container
{
  background-color: blue;
  left:400px;
}
```

Even if I override the *display* property to **block**, it still gives the same output.
Why isn't the division element blocking the space ahead of it?
Output :
[image]

Rather than :

[image]

Comment: make sure you are not using display flex in the parent tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **absolutely positioned element no longer exists in the normal document flow**.
Instead, it sits on its own layer separate from everything else.
Rather than positioning the element based on its relative position within the normal document flow, they specify the distance the element should be from each of the containing element's sides. [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
(the "containing element" is the initial containing block.)
**top, bottom, left, and right use to position that relative to containing block.**

explain reason with your code ---

```
/* when you give 'div' style like this nested div's also get position absolute*/
/* absolute positioned elements positions relative to its nearest positioned element.*/
/* then each container div's positioned relative to its nearest div */
/* comment this div style and use below div for solution. */
div { 
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
}

/* positioned relative to upper div */
.first-container {
background-color: #9ad0ec;
}

/* positioned relative to nearest positioned (first-container) div */
.second-container {
background-color: red;
left: 200px;
}
/* positioned relative to nearest positioned (second-container) div */
.third-container {
background-color: blue;
left: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
<body>
<div>
  <div class="first-container" />
  <div class="second-container" />
  <div class="third-container" />
</div>
</body>
```

need to set 'top' or 'bottom' to container-style to display required output.
check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-architecture-5oc47e?file=/index.html)